# No output when executing stored procedure from mySQL in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Have I done something incorrectly in my implementation of the datatable? This is my first time trying to send queries via Visual Studio (only knew how to query from mySQL) so I may be far off.

There are no compiling errors but running it creates no output whatsoever.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;

 public class sp_criteria
{

public DataTable dataTable(string procedureName, Dictionary<string, object> parameterList)
{
    DataTable outputDataTable;


    using (MySqlConnection MySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;" +
                                            "Port = 1234" +
                                            "Database=heatco;" +
                                            "Uid=root;" +
                                            "Pwd=123456;"))
        MySqlConnection.Open();
    {
        using (MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(procedureName, MySqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (parameterList != null)
            {
                foreach (string key in parameterList.Keys)
                {
                    string parameterName = key;
                    object parameterValue = parameterList[key];


                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("intMaxCFM", 10000));
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("intMinCFM", 2223));
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("intMinMbh", 300));
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("dblDimA", 20000));
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("dblDimB", 20000));
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("dblDimC", 20000));
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("dblDimD", 20000));

                    MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("CALL sp_criteria()", MySqlConnection);
                }
            }

            MySqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            DataSet outputDataSet = new DataSet();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(outputDataSet, "compatibleset");

            outputDataTable = outputDataSet.Tables["compatibleset"];
        }

    }

    return outputDataTable;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any run-time errors?  You don't obviously seem to be checking for them....

Comment: If there were runtime errors thrown by the `SqlCommand` we would be seeing an exception.  It's more likely that the `Fill()` on the adapter isn't returning any rows. Have you executed the stored procedure in SSMS or VS SQL with your parameters equal to what you've got here?

Comment: No run-time errors whatsoever, I've also executed the stored procedure on MySQL with the same parameters and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring a local variable `cm` but never using it:

```
MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("CALL sp_criteria()", MySqlConnection);
```

Instead, set the stored procedure name on `sqlCommand` when you create it (`CALL` is unnecessary). (Also, the braces around `MySqlConnection` in your question look wrong, so I've fixed that here.)

```
using (MySqlConnection MySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
using (MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(procedureName, MySqlConnection))
{
    MySqlConnection.Open();

    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // ADD THIS
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "sp_criteria";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may disposing your connection early

```
using (MySqlConnection MySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;" + "Port = 1234" + "Database=heatco;" + "Uid=root;" + "Pwd=123456;")) 
    MySqlConnection.Open();
```

Looks like you need braces around the statements underneath other wise it will dispose SQL connection straight away.

```
using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection ())
{
    connection.Open();
    // Rest of code
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing curly brace for using connection, you may get compilation error while creating MySqlCommand but I am not sure why. Try this:

```
public DataTable dataTable(string procedureName, Dictionary<string, object> parameterList)
    {
        DataTable outputDataTable;


        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;" +
                                        "Port = 1234" +
                                        "Database=heatco;" +
                                        "Uid=root;" +
                                        "Pwd=123456;")
        {
            connection.Open();
            {
                using (MySqlCommand SqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(procedureName, connection))
                {
                    SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if (parameterList != null)
                {
                    foreach (string key in parameterList.Keys)
                    {
                        string parameterName = key;
                        object parameterValue = parameterList[key];


                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("intMaxCFM", 10000));
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("intMinCFM", 2223));
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("intMinMbh", 300));
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("dblDimA", 20000));
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("dblDimB", 20000));
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("dblDimC", 20000));
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("dblDimD", 20000));

                        MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("CALL sp_criteria()", MySqlConnection);
                    }
                }


                MySqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                    DataSet outputDataSet = new DataSet();
                    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(outputDataSet, "compatibleset");

                    outputDataTable = outputDataSet.Tables["compatibleset"];
                }

            }
        }
        return outputDataTable;
    }
```